# How do I find('list') of HABTM related records for a drop-down in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to generate a list (dropdown) with habtm relationship. For example I have a table called "users" another called "vehicles" and "users_vehicles".

What I want is to get vehicles assigned to "x" user and put it in a drop-down. How can I achieve this?

```
class User extends AppModel {

   var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Vehicle');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one way, there a probably several others.

```
$result = $this->User->Vehicle->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => -1,
    'conditions' => array('Ownership.user_id' => 66),
    'fields' => array('Vehicle.*','Ownership.*'),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'users_vehicles',
            'alias' => 'Ownership',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions'=> 'Vehicle.id = Ownership.vehicle_id'
        )
    )
));
$list = Set::combine($result,'{n}.Vehicle.id','{n}.Vehicle.name');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<code>
$options['conditions']['Ownership.vehicle_id'] = $x;
$options['joins'] = array(
                           array(
                                  'table' => 'ownership',
                                             'alias' => 'Ownership',
                                             'type'  => 'Left',
                                             'conditions' => 'Vehicle.id = Ownership.vehicle_id'
                                            )
                                    );
$this->set('vehicles', $this->Vehicle->find('list', $options));
</code>
```